# A singleton vector is a linear independent set if and only if it is not the zero vector. (Proof Verification)

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

I'm practicing my proof-writing and was hoping you could let me know if this proof looks good. I would like to know if the proof is incorrect, if there are parts that are overly wordy/complicated, or if I'm missing some element of a proof that is helpful to see, if not strictly necessary.

**The Prompt (from [here](https://are.berkeley.edu/courses/ARE211/currentYear/problem_sets/psLinAlgebra1Qu.pdf)):**

A singleton vector is a linear independent set if and only if it is not the zero vector.

**My Proof**:

Suppose a vector v<sup>1</sup> is a linear independent set. Let v<sup>1</sup> be the zero vector. Then t<sub>1</sub>v<sup>1</sup>=0 for all values of t, which contradicts the fact that {v<sup>1</sup>} is a linearly independent set, so v<sup>1</sup> is not the zero vector.

Suppose v<sup>1</sup> is not the zero vector. Then t<sub>1</sub>v<sup>1</sup>=0 only when t<sub>1</sub> = 0, which means that {v<sup>1</sup>} is a linearly independent set.

Comment: In the first part, instead of "for all values of $t$" you need "for at least one non-zero value of $t$" - why not just use $t=1$ explicitly? -- In the second part, how are you sure that $tv=0$ *only* when $t=0$? Perhaps this was already shown, but otherwise note that $tv=0$ with $t\ne 0$ implies $v=1v=t^{-1}tv=t^{-1}0=0$

Comment: That problem set is rather sloppily worded.  The term should always be written *linearly independent* and never *linear independent*.  A singleton is a one-element set, and shouldn't be identified with its one element.  So the prompt should be: “A single vector comprises a linearly independent set iff it is not the zero vector”  Or, “Let $v \in V$.  Then $\{v\}$ is linearly independent if and only if $v \neq 0$.”

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thank you for the feedback on the first part. I don't quite understand what you are saying about the second part. If v<sup>1 is non-zero and t<sub>1</sub>v<sup>1</sup>=0, does that not imply that t<sub>1</sub>=0? In the equation you wrote in your comment, the last equation should be t<sup>-1</sup>0 **!=** 0 (since v != 0), which is a contradiction. That then implies that tv = 0 and t !=0 cannot both be true, and if I know tv=0 then I would conclude that t=0. Let me know if I'm misunderstanding something.